# unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'. and also keep getting error Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

**need help to resolve this error please can someone correct this up? i've commented the line in below code**

```
    discount = Conversion.Val(Dt.Rows[indx]["DiscountRate"]);

    subtotal = (int) ((days * rate) - ((days * rate) * discount));
    *total = System.Convert.ToInt32(((Conversion.Val(subtotal.ToString()) - Conversion.Val(Dt.Rows[indx]["AdvancePayment"].ToString())).ToString("00.00")));*//Input string was not in a correct format.

    if (Conversion.Val(subtotal.ToString()) > Conversion.Val(Dt.Rows[indx]["AdvancePayment"]))
    {
        lv.SubItems.Add(System.Convert.ToString(Conversion.Val(total.ToString())));
    }
    else
    {
        lv.SubItems.Add("0");
    }

    lvlcheckin.Items.Add(lv);
}
rs.Dispose();
Module1.con.Close();
```

Comment: Could you please provide what you are going to achieve with your code and what exact error do you have?

Comment: i am working on a project in windows forms and there on calculation box i tried to do this logic mostly found on internet but keep getting these two errors which are on title of this post.

Comment: **Edit your question** What lines have the errors, and which error is on which line. What are you trying to accomplish with the sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are formatting the `double` using `ToString("00.00")` you cannot convert this string to an Int32...

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Convert.ToInt32("10.00")); // Will generate an error.
```

[image]

If you change your `ToString("00.00")` to `ToString("00")` it will work.

Although in general, I would prefer `Int.TryParse` so you can handle the error conditions.  The following would return -1, if there is a parsing failuer (which there will be).

```
int cvt;

Console.WriteLine(Int32.TryParse("10.00", out cvt)?cvt:-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yout problem is probably inside your if

```
if (Conversion.Val(subtotal.ToString()) > Conversion.Val(Dt.Rows[indx]["AdvancePayment"]))
```

The value of `Dt.Rows[indx]["AdvancePayment"]` is probably dynamic type, but as int not string. You used a ToString() method to calculate the same kind of value of the total variable. So, the sugestion is use ToString( inside the if too:

```
 if (Conversion.Val(subtotal.ToString()) > Conversion.Val(Dt.Rows[indx]["AdvancePayment"].ToString()))
```

Please, next time tell us the line that the error throwed, or a better code (it depends your programming expecience)